# Difficult case to solve - Select + select = result(related data)

Tags: plugins, posts, woocommerce-offtopic

Is it possible to do this with a wordpress plugin? I tried to do it with JetEngine using relation metabox and it didn't work because of the filters

I need that:

1. select printer (taxonomy for now, would be created data)
2. select resin (woocomerce product)
3. result appears printing parameters = metabox or data related between resin and printer. each resin has a different parameter for each printer

there would have to be filters showing the images